# Android Second Spinner Changes Based On Choice In First Spinner

Tags: java, android, dynamic, spinner

First, yes I've browsed through a number of possible solutions and they've gotten me close but I'm missing some small crucial step that I just can not find for the life of me. Everything loads fine. The first spinner (Category) is populated as it should be, I can tell that the second spinner (Color) is getting populated through the create method but I've missed where to tell it to recreate itself when the user selects a Category. Here's all my code as it stands now.

```
package yarn.pack.name;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class YarnDatabaseActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner Category_Add_Spinner = Create_Category_Add_Spinner();
        Spinner Color_Add_Spinner = Create_Color_Add_Spinner(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Creates the Category Spinner for the Add section sends the choice made to
// a method for populating the color spinner
public Spinner Create_Category_Add_Spinner() {
    Spinner Category_Add_Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categoryAddID);
    String[] Category_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.categoryNames);
    SpinnerAdapter Category_Add_Spinner_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            Category_Add_Spinner_Array);
    Category_Add_Spinner.setAdapter(Category_Add_Spinner_Adapter);
    Category_Add_Spinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new Category_Add_Spinner_Listener());
    return Category_Add_Spinner;
}

// The listener for the Category Spinner that sends whatever choice made to
// the method that populates the second spinner.
public class Category_Add_Spinner_Listener implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> Category_Add_Adapter_View,
            View v, int position, long row) {
        String Category_Add_Choice = Category_Add_Adapter_View
                .getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Create_Color_Add_Spinner(Category_Add_Choice);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

// Creates the Color Spinner for the Add section
public Spinner Create_Color_Add_Spinner(String category_Add_Choice) {
    String[] Color_Add_Spinner_Array = null;
    Spinner Color_Add_Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorAddID);
    if (category_Add_Choice == "Red") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.RedColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Pink") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.PinkColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Orange") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.OrangeColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Yellow") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.YellowColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Green") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.GreenColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Blue") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.BlueColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Purple") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.PurpleColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Neutral") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.NeutralColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Mix") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.MixColors);
    } else if (category_Add_Choice == "Fleck") {
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.FleckColors);
    } else
        Color_Add_Spinner_Array = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.MixColors);     
    SpinnerAdapter Color_Add_Spinner_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            Color_Add_Spinner_Array);
    Color_Add_Spinner.setAdapter(Color_Add_Spinner_Adapter);
    Color_Add_Spinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new Color_Add_Spinner_Listener());
    return Color_Add_Spinner;
}
}
```

I'm pretty well certain that whatever I'm missing is something stupidly obvious but I've been working on this for so long and my time is short that I thought I'd reach out here and see if I couldn't get some light shining on the subject. Thanks in advance for any help you all can give me.

---

Sorry about the naming conventions. I generally name so it makes the most sense to myself. Anyway, it turns out that the issue was my using == instead of .equals
Made that change and it worked without a hitch! Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: you should respect java naming conventions, your code is hard to read. http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm. Learn how to use the refactoring menu options in Eclipse, they are pretty useful (renaming is made so easy !)

Comment: what is the result showing when running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost working, not really perfect, but it could work quickly :

1. never use == to compare strings in java. Always use stringA.equals( stringB ). I guess this is your only problem.
2. respect java naming conventions, it would be easier to read.

As pointed out by @Frankenstein, making your widget data members is often more clear and efficient than always re-getting them from the layout using findViewById.

Comment: yeh that is recommanded(equals) but the strange is == also work..I also suggest that.

Comment: intern() must be called on resource arrays when inflating them from xml

Answer (score 0):

Declare this at activity level,

`SpinnerAdapter Category_Add_Spinner_Adapter;`

second step , add this line in onItemSelected at Last.

`Category_Add_Spinner_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

The Change is not reflecting at runtime cause you only changes the value of Array , but the Adapter has assigned the array very long time ago..
So whenever you change the values in your array/arraylist..to reflect those changes in adapter too..you need to notify the adapter that value of underlying array is changes please update your self.

Comment: setting the adapter actually call notifyDataSetChanged. I would have suggested not to recreate an adapter as well, but @fauxfire76 uses an array as source for its adapter.